# Is there an aim assist in State of Decay on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, state-of-decay

I was playing State of Decay on the PC with a keyboard and mouse, now I started to play it with an Xbox controller and I discovered that aiming guns with it is almost impossible. I wasn't able to find an assisted aim mode in the options?

Is there an option to enable aim assist on the PC version?

Answer (score 1):

I am a few years late, but yes there is aim assist - in the form of a survivor specialization. If you specialize into rifles one of the skills your survivor can learn is to aim snap onto a zombie's head at the cost of some stamina.

Outside of that specialization I have noticed some slight aim assist when tracking heads, but not heavy enough to be very useful.